# How to replace all column type from int to bigint in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How to change all column types from `int` to `bigint` in SQL Server?

How to change all stored procedure parameter's types from `int` to `bigint` in SQL Server?

I want replace all `int` with `bigint` to preventing missing some place

Comment: This sounds dangerous.

Comment: Don't do it. If you are asking how to do it then there is so much more than you are unaware of.

Comment: Maybe you are right! Even in IDE, Many place with code like 'int.MaxVaue'

Comment: This way madness lies - it's the same kind of thinking that leads to every string column being a `nvarchar(max)` and you ending up with someone storing the complete works of Shakespeare in one of them. View the (implicit) size constraints as free checks that your data is within proper ranges (or at least orders of magnitude), and use the *correct* sizes based on the known requirements for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can't update all stored procedure at once, first we need to find out all stored procedure which we are declare int type parameters in stored procedure and functions then take one by one from list and update them.

we can find out all procedures and functions which we declare int type parameters using below script.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS WHERE DATA_TYPE='INT'
```

Below script for find out table column data type as INT.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
INNER JOIN
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
ON T.TABLE_CATALOG=C.TABLE_CATALOG
WHERE C.DATA_TYPE='INT'
```

Comment: I Agree, we shouldn't do this.